# How to define a custom selection/mask on an image (script online just after an upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, image, image-processing

I'm looking for a script which allows the creation of a custom selection on a image **online**.
This step is just after an upload.

As a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: here is a picture that illustrates my request]

Does anybody have a script/code/suggestion for me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if you need user input the shape, you can do this by two means:

1. with flash, you could start here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html
2. with javascript, for example with this script (not tested) http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/10/29/clipping-jpeg-images-into-non-rectangular-polygons-using-polyclip-js/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Polyclip was very interesting!
I combined it with [this script](http://www.javascriptfr.com/codes/DESSINER-POLYGONES-AVEC-SOURIS_51910.aspx) to obtain the coords!